# Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:4444 Selenium Grid Docker

Tags: docker, selenium, grid

I have created a docker image of the test automation framework. I am using the docker-compose file to run the selenium Grid (hub and nodes) for chrome, firefox, and edge.

But I get the following error while the container is run.
[image]

**It works absolutely fine while running the docker-compose file on local without making the docker image of the whole framework.**

**Below is the docker-compose that I have been using.**

```html
# To execute this docker-compose yml file use `docker-compose -f docker-compose-v3.yml up`
# Add the `-d` flag at the end for detached execution
# To stop the execution, hit Ctrl+C, and then `docker-compose -f docker-compose-v3.yml down`
version: "3"
services:

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.1.1-20211217
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"
      - "4445:4445"

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.1.1-20211217
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4444
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4444

  edge:
    image: selenium/node-edge:4.1.1-20211217
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4444
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4444

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:4.1.1-20211217
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4444
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4444

  opera:
    image: selenium/node-opera:latest
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4445
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4445
```

**The browser invoking is happening as below**

driver = (new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remote_url), win_Options)); // url is the remote webdriver pointing to the docker container running

Answer (score 1):

For me, it worked by adding `--network="host"`  in the run command

```
docker run -d --network="host" image-name
```